# Possible to use data.table's rbindlist in a pipe

Tags: r, data.table, magrittr

Is it possible to use `data.table` `rbindlist` in a piped operation? I posted a MWE below. I try to create a `data.table` c by piping in the `rbindlist` but get an error.

Instead, I have to manipulate c and then assign the `rbindlist` to c (but c is used within the `list` argument in `rbindlist`. If possible, I would like to avoid that, which I tried to accomplish through the `rbindlist` in the pipe up above. Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

a <- data.table(colA = 1:10,
                colB = 11:20)

b <- data.table(colA = 300,
                colB = 500)

c <- a %>% 
  .[, colB := colB * 10] %>% 
  rbindlist(list(.,b),
            use.names = TRUE,
            fill = TRUE)
#> Error in rbindlist(., list(., b), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE): idcol must be a logical or character vector of length 1. If logical TRUE the id column will named '.id'.

c <- a %>% 
  .[, colB := colB * 10]

c <- rbindlist(list(c,b),
               use.names = TRUE,
               fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: why `rbindlist` and not `bind_rows` ?  You could do `a %>%
  mutate(colB = colB * 10) %>%
  bind_rows(b)
` right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed possible, but you want to use extra braces for that:

```
c <- a %>% 
  .[, colB := colB * 10] %>% 
  {rbindlist(list(.,b), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)}
```

The reason for this is pretty evident from the error itself:

```
# Error in rbindlist(., list(., b), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE): ...
```

That is, your attempt is equivalent to

```
rbindlist(aTransformed, list(aTransformed, b), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

which clearly wasn't your intention and does not work as `rbindlist` wants to receive a list of objects to bind as the first argument. Now if we want to use the shortcut `.` but don't want to pass the data to the first argument, we can use extra brackets `{}` to create an expression. Expressions are of type `{x <- 2; y <- x^2; y + x}` returning `y + x`, so it kind of makes sense that `%>%` doesn't that to pass the data as the first argument, since there is none.

Comment: That does work. I'm sorry but could you explain a little further into the meaning of the error please and why enclosing `rbindlist` in `{}` is necessary?

Comment: @Prevost, sure, I added some more comments.

Answer (score 4):

While Julius' solution works great, wouldn't this simpler solution work for your purposes?

```
c <- a %>% 
  .[, colB := colB * 10] %>% 
  list(b) %>%
  rbindlist(use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)

# without pipes:
c <- 
  rbindlist(
    list(
      a[, colB := colB * 10], 
      b
    ), 
    use.names = TRUE, 
    fill = TRUE
  )
```

Comment: Why can you omit the list argument from `rbindlist`? That produces the desired result also.

Comment: Has to do with how the pipe (`%>%`) works. What's on the LHS (left-hand side) becomes the first argument of what's one the RHS. I will add the equivalent code without any pipes to shed light on this.

Comment: Right, I was under the impression that I always had to insert `.` for the function argument when using `%>%` but apparently not!

Comment: @Prevost You can always insert it, but if you don't it will be assumed to be the first argument.

Comment: In other words: `5 %>% sum(3)` is `5 %>% sum(., 3)`.